# POSTGRESQL at least 8 characters in name with LIKE or REGEX

Tags: regex, postgresql

```
SELECT name
FROM players
WHERE name ~ '(.*){8,}'
```

It is really simple but I cannot seem to get it. 
I have a list with names and I have to filter out the ones with at least 8 characters... But I still get the full list.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you simply looking for `where char_length(name) < 8`?

Comment: Yes, thank you :) I was making it too difficult... ;p

Comment: BTW the regex pattern would be `'.{8,}'` or the `LIKE` pattern would be `'________%'`. But OFC, checking the length is so much easier.

Comment: this work: select first_name, last_name from names
where first_name like '________%'

Answer (score 2):

A `(.*){8,}` regex means *match any zero or more chars 8 or more times*.

If you want to match any 8 or more chars, you would use `.{8,}`.

However, using [`character_lenth`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) is more appropriate for this task:

> `char_length(string)` or `character_length(string)`    *int*       Number of characters in string

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (s character varying)
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (s)
VALUES
    ('abc'),
    ('abc45678'),
    ('abc45678910')
;
SELECT * from table1 WHERE character_length(s) >= 8;
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/GRWYD43479)

[image]